# How to import data to database using jenkins pipeline?

Tags: sql, jenkins, jdbc

I'm really new to jenkins.

I want to know how to import data to database in pipeline. (Database is Oracle 11g)

I tried some examples on web site, but nothing helpful.

Some article tells to me the solution, but I'm failed..

below is my example.

[image]

and error log.

```html
Started by user admin
Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in C:\Users\SIT\.jenkins\workspace\pipeline
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.oracle.jdbc.Driver
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1333)
 at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteClassLoader.loadClass(CallSiteClassLoader.java:54)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.loadClass(ClassLoaderForClassArtifacts.java:60)
 at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
 at java_lang_Class$forName$1.call(Unknown Source)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:113)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.methodCall(DefaultInvoker.java:20)
 at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:3)
 at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:57)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:109)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:82)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:122)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:261)
 at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:174)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:332)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$200(CpsThreadGroup.java:83)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:244)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:232)
 at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:64)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:131)
 at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
 at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:59)
 at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
 at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Finished: FAILURE
```

I think I need jdbc driver, but I can't find how to do that.

Is anyone know how to solve it or reference site??
Please help..

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [**SQLPlus Script Runner plug-in**](https://plugins.jenkins.io/sqlplus-script-runner) in **Jenkins**.

> This plugin enables you run Oracle SQL*Plus scripts on your Jenkins
>   jobs (user defined scripts or a script inside a workspace).

Comment: I solve that problem to download JDBC driver.
I have another question. I want to connect remote oracle database in jenkins pipeline.
But I don't know how to connect to oracle DB. Do you know how to do that? or have reference document??

Comment: You can upvote & accept this answer if it helps, please raise separate questions for each problem, so that the topic stays relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the JDBC driver from [this location](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html).